# Format decimal display in Sinatra app

Tags: html, ruby, forms, sinatra

I have a price field in my Sinatra app. The DataMapper definition is:

`property :purchase_price, Decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 2`

The input form, where the price is collected reads like this:

`<input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price" pattern="^\d+\.\d{2}$">`

And the edit form, where I'd like to see the price and potentially change it, looks like this:

`<input type="text" name="price" value="<%= @book.purchase_price.to_s('F') %>">`

When I display all the books and their prices in a table, the price is displayed via:

`<td><%= book.purchase_price.to_s('F') %></td>`

where that line is in a loop:

`<% @books.each do |book| %> 
... 
<% end %>`

The price display truncates the cents portion of the value when cents equals zero, i.e., I get `9.0` instead of `9.00`. The input pattern ensures that I have to enter `9.00`, but I cannot figure out how to display `9.00`.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. How do I display the price without it truncating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"%.2f" % @book.purchase_price
```

will format your variable with two decimal places. Equivalently,

```
sprintf("%.2f", @book.purchase_price)
```

Documentation: [String#%](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25), [Kernel#sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Money gem https://github.com/RubyMoney/money.